# Can we have a rule just only write permission without read permission in firebase firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

As the title, I just want an authenticated user is allowed to write to a collection in firestore, but is not allow to read data of the collection. Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.  Simply do not grant read access in the rule for that collection.

```
match /collection/{id} {
  allow write: if request.auth != null;
}
```

This is easy to test for yourself using the rules simulator in the Firestore console.